# proto node js new Schema.Employee() not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers, webstorm

I am learning proto buf https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46O73On0gyI

File `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "vy_learn_proto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "google-protobuf": "^3.21.2"
  }
}
```

```
C:\Windows\system32>protoc --version
libprotoc 3.12.4
```

File `employees.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Employee{
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  float salary = 3;
}

message Employees{
  repeated Employee employees = 1;
}
```

Generate js file from proto file.

```
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. employees.proto
```

My file `index2.js`

```js
const Schema = require("./employees_pb");

// import

const hussein = new Schema.Employee();
```

syntax error at `Schema.Employee();` , I need fix and understand problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to revise/fix this problem?
(Source code from author https://github.com/hnasr/javascript_playground/blob/master/protobuff/index2.js#L3 )

Comment: Will installing **Protocol Buffers** plugin help?

Comment: What plug-in I should add https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/221825605-c96d30b5-801c-4c28-a33e-a00fa03a6b8b.png ?

Comment: The one which I have stated (exact name): Protocol Buffers (#1 on your screenshot). But it appears that you have it installed already. Maybe it does not work with JavaScript properly?.. Sorry, no better ideas from me.